# How to configure coredns Corefile similar to unbound configurations?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, coredns

Is there a possibility to configure all the unbound configurations listed [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/unbound.conf) similarly in kubernetes coredns 'Corefile' configuration like this. Only few options are listed [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/). I am looking for the below server options in unbound conf to be done on kubernetes Corefile coredns configmap.

1. do-ip6
2. verbosity
3. outgoing-port-avoid, outgoing-port-permit
4. domain-insecure
5. access-control
6. local-zone

I need to do above configurations similarly in kubernetes Corefile configuration. As I am new to kubernetes coredns, I am not sure whether these configurations are possible in Coredns. Can someone direct me how to do that? Also I am looking for steps on how to configure this in Corefile  configmap using helm. It would be really helpful if I get some information on this. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `Also I am looking for steps on how to configure this in Corefile configmap using helm`? Coredns is a built-in component of kubernetes cluster. Helm is used for development and shipment of applications, see [more details](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/)

Comment: @moonkotte Yes you are correct but when we fresh install a pod in default namespace, how to automate these custom configurations in coredns (kube-system namespace) during helm install pod itself. And I see we need to restart the coredns pod after doing custom configurations in corefile configmap. Can we do these configurations during installation of pod somewhere by specifying Corefile configmap changes in helm? Instead doing using kubectl apply command to apply configmap changes?

Comment: Coredns is located in `kube-system` namespace. You only need to change its config if you deploy a new cluster. Any newly deployed pods will be using `coredns` which already exists. Also there's a flag for graceful reload of `coredns` when configmap is changed.

Comment: @moonkotte Thanks for the info. Are you aware of my other question on how to do mentioned unbound configuration in coredns

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CoreDNS` supports some requested features via [`plugins`](https://coredns.io/plugins/):

- `do-ip6` - CoreDNS works with ipv6 by default (if cluster is dual-stack)
- `verbosity` - [`log`](https://coredns.io/plugins/log/) plugin will show more details about queries, it can have different format and what it shows (success, denial, errors, everything)
- `outgoing-port-avoid, outgoing-port-permit` - did not find any support of this
- `domain-insecure` - please check if [`dnssec`](https://coredns.io/plugins/dnssec/) can help (It looks similar to what `unbound` has, but I'm not really familiar with it).
- `access-control` - [`acl`](https://coredns.io/plugins/acl/) plugin does it.
- `local-zone` - [`local`](https://coredns.io/plugins/local/) plugin can be tried for this purpose, it doesn't have lots of options though.

Bonus point:

- CoreDNS config's change - [`reload`](https://coredns.io/plugins/reload/) allows automatic reload of a changed Corefile.

All mentioned above plugins have syntax and examples on their pages.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I still have doubt in using local plugin, in unbound the syntax is local-zone: <zone> <type> but in coredns the syntax is simply inside the server block we need to give as local. Eg:  .:53 { local }. Can you please provide an example to use local plugin to work similar to local-zone: <zone> <type> i.e, local-zone: 10.in-addr.arpa nodefault  ?

Comment: @anonymoususer Example of plugin is provided on their page. It won't work exactly as `unbound` does. You need to test it if it fits your needs/expectations. As far as I understand, it should work the same way `unbound` does, however I did not use `unbound` to claim it 100%.